# Spark performance difference in join

Tags: dataframe, scala, apache-spark

I have 2 data frames and partitioned on a column `partition_column`, I am observing performance difference between, below 2 approaches while joining the data frames.

Let say 2 data frames are df1 and df2 and both are partitioned on `partition_column`.

1. Joining data frame by using spark parallelism.

```
val writeDF = df1.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"),
            col("df1.partition_column").equalTo("df2.partition_column")
            and col("df1.unique_id").equalTo(col("df2.unique_id"))).select("df1.*")
writeDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("partition_column").parquet("some location")
```

I checked spark plan and it's using partition filters, but this work slow compare to below approach.

2. joining data frame by submitting partitions in group.

```
val partitions = df2.select("partition_column").distinct.collect() //i have maximum 500 partitions
    partitions.grouped(5).foreach(batches=>{
        batches.par.foreach(row=>{
          val partitionKey = row.getAs[Double]("partition_column")
          val writeDF = df1.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"),
            col("df1.partition_column").equalTo(partitionKey)
            and col("df2.partition_column").equalTo(partitionKey)
            and col("df1.unique_id").equalTo(col("df2.unique_id"))).select("df1.*")
writeDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(s"somebase_location/partition_column=${partitionKey}/")
        })
    })
```

This approach is also using partition filter in their plan.

One thing which i observed is resource utilization, in approach 1 resource utilization is 30%, but in approach 2 it's around 75%.

My questions are:

1. Why 2 approach is faster than 1 approach.
2. As I need data from 1 data frame, should I go for filtering approach.

**EDIT- 24-06-2023**

After analyzing jobs and stages on spark UI found below things.
Approach first:

1. spark is reading all partitions as it is parquet hive table, after adding one more filter related to required partition, It's reading only required partitions and creating 2 jobs, one if performing map-reduce process and second is writing processed data.There is property `spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning` When true, some predicates will be pushed down into the Hive metastore so that un-matching partitions can be eliminated earlier, but not yet tried.

```
val partitions = df2.select("partition_column").distinct.collect()
val partitionsKeys = partitions.map(key=>key.getInt(0))
val writeDF = df1.as("df1").join(df2.as("df2"),
col("df1.partition_column").isin(partitionsKeys:_*)  
and  col("df1.partition_column").equalTo("df2.partition_column")
            and col("df1.unique_id").equalTo(col("df2.unique_id"))).select("df1.*")
writeDF.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).partitionBy("partition_column").parquet("some location")
```

2. After reading data it's shorting all records and shuffling data, shuffle writing is happening in tarabytes.
3. Then it's performing sortmerge join and finally writing data.

Second approach:

1. In approach second, spark is reading 1-1 partitions in group of 5 partitions. As it's joining 1-1 partition creating more jobs compare to first approach.
2. Sorting data and performing broadcast join as second data frame is very small in size and finally writing data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your actual question is, but it makes sense that the second approach would take more memory usage, it basically does almost the same join about 500 times. One thing that makes me curious about both queries is that there is no need for joins when we only need the columns of one table, You may also want to try this:

```scala
df2.registerTempTable("df2")

val writeDF = df1.as("df1").where(
  expr("exists (select true from df2 where df2.partition_column = df1.partition_column and df2.unique_id = df1.unique_id)")
)
```

Or if you want to use spark APIs, I think the most similar API to `EXISTS` is left semi join:

```scala
df1.join(
  df2,
  df1("partition_column") === df2("partition_column") and df1("unique_id") === df2("unique_id"),
  "left_semi"
)
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your response, so my question is why 2 approach is faster than 1 approach. I am getting almost 2hours difference in processing

Comment: @sandeeptiwari Oh I get it now, unfortunately I cannot probably help you in that, but I wonder what would happen in case of the approach I provided. If you could try that, I would be happy to know about the results :)